# why does $_GET not work in functions.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

my url query string is `http://website.local/residences/?status=status2&type=apartments&price=null`

When I echo $_GET['status'] from my page template I get 'status2', which is obviously correct.
But I try to get that value from my functions.php it returns false. I'm using ajax to load in more posts with the below function. It should be getting that status value with $_GET for the tax query.. No idea why it's returning false only in my functions.php.

Any ideas?

```
function load_more_members($offset = 0, $post_type = 'project'){

    $offset = 0;
    $post_type = 'project';
    $status_array = array();
    $tax_arr = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    );

    if(isset($_POST['offset'])) {
        $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['post_type'])) {
        $post_type = $_POST['post_type'];
    }    

    if (isset($_GET['status']) && !empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] !== 'null') {
        $status = $_GET['status'];
        array_push($status_array, array(
            'taxonomy' => 'status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $status,
        ));
    }


    if (!empty($status_array)) {
        array_push($tax_arr, $status_array);
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'offset' => $offset,
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'order_by'  => 'date',
          'tax_query' => $tax_arr
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    $posts_left = $offset + 4;
    $found_posts = $the_query->found_posts;

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        ob_start();
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();  
                echo get_template_part('template-parts/latest', 'loop');
        endwhile; 
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    endif; 
    
    echo json_encode(array(
        'html' => $output,
        'offset' => $posts_left,
        'found_posts' => $found_posts
    ));
    exit();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_members', 'load_more_members');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_members', 'load_more_members');
```

```
  function load_more_posts(offset, post_type) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: WPURLS.ajax_url,
      data: {
        action: "load_more_members",
        offset: offset,
        post_type: post_type,
      },
      beforeSend: function (data) {
        $(".load-more-" + post_type).addClass("loading");
      },
      success: function (response) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $("." + post_type + "-repeat").append(obj.html);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("est" + error);
      },
    });
  }
$(".load-more-post").on("click tap touch", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var this_offset = $(this).attr("data-offset");
    load_more_posts(this_offset, "post");
  });
```

Comment: i don't see you calling the function `load_more_members()`, are you sure you are calling it?

Comment: I've just added the jQuery that's calling "load_more_members". Any idea why $_GET isn't working from functions.php?

Comment: you should call `load_more_members` from php, not jquery

Comment: Why? It's running off a click event and I'm using ajax to pull the posts

Comment: it calls the file, the file contains the function, but it's not firing it, it needs to fire it

Comment: I just included my add action to the php. It is working. But it's not getting the $_GET value.
I'm pulling in posts just fine with this function, just the $_GET not working

Comment: @matt.mcg checkout my suggested answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to get it inside of an AJAX callback function, $_GET will not work as you expect.

As a result, I am providing you with an alternative solution to your problem that I believe will be helpful to you.

**You can get the query string by putting the below function in your JS file.**

```
function getQueryString() {
    let string = [], hash;
    let hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        string.push(hash[0]);
        string[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return string;
}
```

You can get the value of a query string like `let status = getQueryString()["status"];` and pass it to the `data` in your ajax call.

```
function load_more_posts(offset, post_type) {
    let status = getQueryString()["status"];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: WPURLS.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: "load_more_members",
            offset: offset,
            post_type: post_type,
            status: status
        },
        beforeSend: function (data) {
            $(".load-more-" + post_type).addClass("loading");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $("." + post_type + "-repeat").append(obj.html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("est" + error);
        },
    });
}
$(".load-more-post").on("click tap touch", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var this_offset = $(this).attr("data-offset");
    load_more_posts(this_offset, "post");
});
```

Now, you can get the value in your ajax call.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_members', 'load_more_members');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_members', 'load_more_members');

function load_more_members()
{
    echo $_POST['status'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET` will not work as you expect it to work, because you're trying to get it inside the ajax callback function.

`http://website.local/residences/?status=status2&type=apartments&price=null`

In the above url, you can get the param only when this url loads, but once this url loads and you call a WP Ajax then url becomes like this `http://website.local/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` in which there is no param for `$_GET`

so you'll have to collect `$_GET` when your page loads then store those `$_GET` values into either js object or in HTML data attributes then you need to pass those values to your js and then you'll pass those variables as `$_POST` and will collect them using `$_POST` in your ajax callback function.